# HttpContext.Current is null when using async

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to call an async method that needs to read a file from the server. Whenever the method is async, `HttpContext.Current` becomes null. If I call it normally, it works fine. How do I go around this?

My code is:

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path))
```

Comment: this could help: http://www.rahulsingla.com/blog/2010/09/asp-net-httpcontext-current-is-null-in-endxxx-method-of-asynchronous-web-methods-pair

Answer (score 3):

The correct class to call is `HostingEnvironment.MapPath(path);`

Thanks for the tip bvs.

Answer (score 2):

Use [HostedEnvironment.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.mappath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead:

`System.IO.File.ReadAllText(HostedEnvironment.MapPath(path))`

Answer (score 1):

Here - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/11/19/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework.aspx - is a documentation about HttpContext used with async/await.

To cut a long story short you need to do one of two things:

- Set key in application settings: `<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />`
- Set your framework to 4.5